# How would you use sorting to find whether there is a gap between the union of some integer ranges?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that you have ranges declared from 0 to N

these ranges are in the form of [a,b] where `0<=a,b<=N`

to find whether there's a gap between the union, I would probably sort all `a, b` values and make it clear which one is a starting point and which one is an ending point.

Then I would scan it and if there's a gap between an ending point and a starting point, then we found a gap so we finish.

would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is basically correct, although you need to keep track of the right-most ending point you've encountered so far. A good test case for this would be [1, 5], [2, 3], [4, 6].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basically the idea, but you have to deal with overlapping ranges. The easiest way to do that is to just ignore the connection between starting points and ending points, and look only at the count of ranges at a given point:

For example, here are some ranges:

```
                                     ----------
                       -------------------     ---  -------
                 -----------         ---------------  ----    ----
Vertical count: 011111122222111122222333332222222211111111100011110
The union:       ------------------------------------------   ----
```

In the original set of ranges, there are points which are in up to three of the ranges (and even that was just arbitrary). We can compute the count, and consequently the union, by sorting the starting and ending points, and then simply sweeping from left to right.

If we start just a little to the left of the ranges (at -1, for example), we're at a point in 0 ranges. As we move right, we'll hit starting points and ending points. Crossing a starting point increases the number of ranges we're in; crossing an ending point decreases it. We don't need to know which starting point corresponds to which ending point to keep an accurate count of the number of ranges.

We can compute the union while we sweep by starting with an empty vector, and then inserting a starting point when the range count changes from 0 to a positive value, and an ending point when it changes from a positive value to 0. (Since the ranges in this example are fully inclusive, we need to be careful to process starting points before ending points in the scan.) If we add more than one starting point to the union, the union is disjoint.